# Snowflake stored procedure calling multiple statements with iterative return messages

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to make a stored procedure in Snowflake that runs 5 COPY INTO commands.  I'm currently testing with only 2 so that I can better isolate the issues.  I'd like each command to run and return "X is good to go!"

Here is what I have currently.  It saves, and it runs, but it only returns one message, and doesn't run the second statement.

```
create or replace procedure copy_into_tables()
  returns string
  language javascript
  as
  $$


sql_cmd1 =  `copy into "SFDVDH"."SCHEMA"."STG_AUTOMATION_DATA_DAILY"
from (select $1,
  $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,
  current_timestamp(),metadata$filename,iff(split_part(metadata$filename,'_',8)='Partial.txt','Yes','')
from @SFDVDH.SCHEMA.stage)
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = SFDVDH.SCHEMA.FORMAT_CSV)
pattern ='.*Automation_Data.*';`

var data1_copy= snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: sql_cmd1 } );
var res1= data1_copy.execute();
return 'Data1 good to go!';

sql_cmd2 =  `copy into "SFDVDH"."SCHEMA"."STG_AUTOMATION_DATA_WEEKLY"
from (select $1,
  $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,
  current_timestamp(),metadata$filename,iff(split_part(metadata$filename,'_',8)='Partial.txt','Yes','')
from @SFDVDH.SCHEMA.stage)
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = SFDVDH.SCHEMA.FORMAT_CSV)
pattern ='.*Automation_Data2.*';`

var Data2_copy= snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: sql_cmd2 } );
var res2= spotradio_copy.execute();
return 'Data2 good to go!';

$$;
```

I have looked through this site as well as many sources and can't find a way to make this work.  The answers on this site haven't helped either.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages a function can only return once - once you hit the `return x` point, the function returns and stops executing anything after it.

So the simplest solution to the problem above is to not `return 'Data1 good to go!'`. Just set a variable, and return it later, when you are ready to `return 'Data2 good to go!'`.

A more complex alternative would be to use Snowflake streams and tasks -- but it's not clear to me yet in what context you want to execute all this. If you ask a new question giving more details about your goals, we can find a way about that. But for this question: A function can't return twice in most languages, and -certainly- not here.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Using-Streams-and-Tasks-inside-Snowflake

Comment: Thanks Felipe.  this is a stored procedure, wrapped in a task, that is executing statements on streams.

Comment: Oh, so if it's already wrapped in a task, then you could have multiple tasks depending on the execution of each other. Then each task gets to return once, and the next one starts running as soon as the previous one returns.